# Main js file doesn't import created chunked file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've come across a problem. All entry js files defined in webpack are created and same goes for chunked vendor files. In webpack i have optimization section defined like:

```
optimization: {
   splitChunks: {
       chunks: "all"
    }
}
```

Inside my dist folder everything looks fine: content files are there, js and chunked vendor file are generated but when I access site js file is fetched properly but next none of my content, nor chunked vendor is fetched.

[Invalid result - blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsak.png)

This is my webpack configuration i use. Without optimization section all the content(img, fonts) and js files are provided with success.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    tppauth: "./src/pages/tppauth.js",
    notfound: "./src/pages/notfound.js",
    servererror: "./src/pages/servererror.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "/dist/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|png|gif|svg)?$/,
        use: { loader: "file-loader" }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(less|css)$/,
        use: ["style-loader","css-loader","less-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      ['~']: __dirname
    }
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks : {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  },
};
```

My js file which renders some other defined components

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import dateFormat from "dateformat";

import "~/Content/Styles/container.less";

class PaymentAuthorization extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...this.state,
      request: {}
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <IntlProvider locale="fr" messages={messages["fr"]}>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <div className="center">{ComponentToRender}</div>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<PaymentAuthorization/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Am i missing some additional import in js file when I'm trying to chunk files?
[Valid response - without otpimization section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpnIh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after few weeks of break I found what I did wrong. I didn't add `<script src='...' />` tags for new bundled files.

I used html-webpack-plugin to get my html template and put needed javascript files to it but it can be done manually aswell. 
These is my new cshtml file where node_modules are split into two separate files:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LayoutPage.cshtml";
}<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/vendor2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/vendor1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/tppauth.js"></script>
```